# Query to get the row counts of all the tables in a database in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the query to get the row counts of all the tables in Snowflake database.

Answer (score 13):

Please use below query:

```
SELECT t.table_schema || '.' ||  t.table_name as "table_name",t.row_count
FROM information_schema.tables t
WHERE t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY t.row_count
```

Comment: can you explain your query

Comment: Make sure to set your worksheet context correctly by running below queries


`use database my_db;
use schema my_schema;`

Answer (score 6):

I'd take a different approach and use the TABLES view in the ACCOUNT_USAGE share.  There may be some latency, but for larger Snowflake accounts I leverage the ACCOUNT_USAGE share all the time for things like this.

The following gives you the record count, a "list" of the table names, and the number of tables for a given Database and schema, you can tweak the query to meet your needs.

```
SELECT SUM(row_count) total_row_count, listagg(table_name, ' ') tab_list, count(*) num_tabs
FROM   snowflake.account_usage.tables
WHERE  table_catalog = 'DB NAME HERE'
AND    table_schema = 'SCHEMA NAME HERE'
AND    table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
AND    deleted IS NULL;
```

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/tables.html

I hope this helps...Rich Murnane

Comment: As Rich mentioned, this has some latency, but the biggest benefit is that you can query all databases and schemas at the same time, if you wish, while information_schema is limited to a single database (and only includes tables that you have access to).

Answer (score 1):

```
select TABLE_CATALOG||'.'||TABLE_SCHEMA||'.'||TABLE_NAME FQN,ROW_COUNT from YOURDATABASE.information_schema.tables where table_type = 'BASE TABLE';

+------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| FQN                                            | ROW_COUNT |
|------------------------------------------------+-----------|
| YOURDATABASE.PUBLIC.FOO1                       |   7108958 |
| YOURDATABASE.PUBLIC.FOO2                       |    444847 |
| YOURDATABASE.PUBLIC.FOO3                       |   2048267 |
| YOURDATABASE.PUBLIC.FOO4                       |       212 |
+------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my results using this simplest query :

```
use your_db_name.information_schema;
select * from tables where table_schema ='Your_schema_name';
```

Happy Querying :)